# Modify values inside sql SELECT query

Tags: sql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT town,latitude,longitude FROM coordinates
```

The following will return e.g

```
"California,10.02313,20.123213"
```

I am using the query results to place markers on gmaps. But if i have 10 markers for California, they will pile up, since the coordinates are the same.

What i want to add a (very small) random number to lat and lng so markers will appear inside california's limits but they wont pile up.

How can i add, lets say `FLOOR(RAND() * 0.0030)+0.0040` to lat and lng so the result will be:

```
"1,California,10.02322,20.123254"
"2,California,10.02313,20.123213"
```

Notice the small change in coordinates, but still inside California's state limits(with very little variation)

Comment: I also see you added a row number to the SQL, but you don't state it in your question?

Comment: Just to show that the query will return multiple rows.

Comment: @ConradFrix I was asking if the Row Number was something the OP wanted in the desired results, actually. Not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @Invent-Animate doh! I misunderstood the question thinking that you misunderstood the OP's question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT` can be followed by arbitrary expressions, they don't have to be just column names. So you can write:

```
SELECT town,
       latitude + FLOOR(RAND() * 0.0030)+0.0040 AS latitude,
       longitude + FLOOR(RAND() * 0.0030)+0.0040 AS longitude
```

Comment: Doesn't `FLOOR(RAND() * 0.0030)` always return 0?

Comment: @Invent-Animate Yes. The answer is really more generic, any expression can be used. Whether it's the right formula for what he wants is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

The +0.004 is unnecessary since it does not randomize the data, it just adds a constant to it

`SELECT town, FLOOR(RAND() * 0.0030) + latitude as latitude, FLOOR(RAND() * 0.0030) + longitude as longitude FROM coordinates`

I would also suggest not adding floor since it would probably just add 0 to the column (since it rounds the offset down to an integer) instead do something like

`SELECT town, (RAND() * 0.0030 + latitude) as latitude, (RAND() * 0.0030 + longitude) as longitude FROM coordinates`